# Chatify in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, pusher

can't search for name based on auth how to do it? in my project

I use auth for admin and user, but when I search by nama_ibu in the users database it doesn't exist

```
'nama_ibu' => env('CHATIFY_NAME', 'Chatify Messenger'),

'storage_disk_name' => env('CHATIFY_STORAGE_DISK', 'public'),

 'routes' => [
        'prefix' => env('CHATIFY_ROUTES_PREFIX', 'chatify'),
        'middleware' => env('CHATIFY_ROUTES_MIDDLEWARE', ['web','auth']),
        'namespace' => env('CHATIFY_ROUTES_NAMESPACE', 'Chatify\Http\Controllers'),
    ],
    'api_routes' => [
        'prefix' => env('CHATIFY_API_ROUTES_PREFIX', 'chatify/api'),
        'middleware' => env('CHATIFY_API_ROUTES_MIDDLEWARE', ['api']),
        'namespace' => env('CHATIFY_API_ROUTES_NAMESPACE', 'Chatify\Http\Controllers\Api'),
    ],
```

**web.php**

```
Route::middleware('web', 'auth')->group(function () {
        
    Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin'])->group(function(){
        
    Route::get('admin', [DashboardController::class, 'index']) >name('admin.dashboard');

});
```

```
Route::middleware(['user'])->group(function(){
        Route::get('user', function (){
            return view('user.dashboard');
        })->name('user');
});
```

[image]